# WPGraphQL query by custom post type taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, graphql, wp-graphql

Currently I have created custom post type with custom taxonomies called "Countries" and "Practice areas". And in case of simple posts I can just do:

[image]

But with custom taxonomies I can't do the same.
My goal is to query all persons that contains taxonomy "country - estonia" and "Practice area - all". What I'm currently allowed to do is:

[image]

Or:

[image]

Is there any logical operators in WPGraphQL, or I have smthing wrongly setted now?

I would greatly appreciate, any advice!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Ice_mank normal solution - no, workaround is to use nested categories

Answer (score 2):

WPGraphQL doesn't natively support filtering a query for custom post types by their taxonomy.

But, you can add your own clause by adding this code (and adjusting the fields to suit your requirements) in your functions.php file :

```
// First, we register the field in the "where" clause.
add_action('graphql_register_types', function () {

    $customposttype_graphql_single_name = "Country"; // Replace this with your custom post type single name in PascalCase

    // Registering the 'categorySlug' argument in the 'where' clause.
    // Feel free to change the name 'categorySlug' to something that suits your requirements.
    register_graphql_field('RootQueryTo' . $customposttype_graphql_single_name . 'ConnectionWhereArgs', 'categorySlug', [
        'type' => [ 'list_of' => 'String' ], // To accept multiple strings
        'description' => __('Filter by post objects that have the specific category slug', 'your_text_domain'),
    ]);
});

// Next, we add a filter to modify the query arguments.
add_filter('graphql_post_object_connection_query_args', function ($query_args, $source, $args, $context, $info) {

    $categorySlug = $args['where']['categorySlug']; // Accessing the 'categorySlug' argument.

    if (isset($categorySlug)) {
        // If the 'categorySlug' argument is provided, we add it to the tax_query.
        // For more details, refer to the WP_Query class documentation at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
        $query_args['tax_query'] = [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy', // Replace 'your_taxonomy' with your actual taxonomy key
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $categorySlug
            ]
        ];
    }

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 5);
```

After applying these changes, you should be able to retrieve a list of your custom posts filtered by your taxonomy like this :

```
query GetCountries {
  countries(where: { categorySlug: ["united-states", "france"] }) {
    nodes {
      id
    }
  }
}
```